# orlicz sequence space

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $M$ and $N$ be mutually complementary Orlicz functions.
The Orlicz sequence space is defined as $$\ell_M=\{x\in\mathbb{K}^\mathbb{N}:\sum_{i\geq1}x_i y_i\text{ convergence for all }y\in y\in\tilde{\ell_N}\}$$ with $$\tilde{\ell_N}=\{x\in\mathbb{K}^\mathbb{N}:\sum_{i\geq1}N(|x_i|)\leq\infty\}\text{ and }\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{C}.$$
In the paper that i read, they say $\ell_M$ is clearly banach space with respect to norm $\|.\|_M$ given by $$\|x\|_M=\sup\{|\sum_{i\geq1} x_i y_i|:\sum_{i\geq1}N(|y_i|)\leq1\}.$$ But, i can't see that the proof is clear. Any idea how to proof completeness here?